# What is a "free variable"?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

(I'm sure this must have been answered on this site already, but search gets inundated with the concept of calling free() on a variable in C.)

I came across the term "eta reduction," which was defined something like `f x = M x ==> M` if x is "not free in M". I mean, I think I understand the gist of what it's trying to say, it seems like what you do when you convert a function to point-free style, but I don't know what the qualifier about x not being free means.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
\f -> f x
```

In this lambda, `x` is a free variable. Basically a free variable is a variable used in a lambda that is not one of the lambda's arguments (or a `let` variable). It comes from outside the context of the lambda.

Eta reduction means we can change:

```
(\x -> g x) to (g)
```

But only if `x` is not free (i.e. it is not used or is an argument) in `g`. Otherwise we'd be creating an expression which refers to a unknown variable:

```
(\x -> (x+) x) to (x+) ???
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: it can be okay for `x` to be used, if it is bound. Eta-reducing `(\x -> (\x -> x + x) x)` to `(\x -> x + x)` is perfectly okay, even though `(\x -> x + x)` contains two uses of `x`. This is a corner case which won't show up much in dealing with human-written code, but I imagine compilers will run across this more often.

Comment: I messed up the wording a bit there. "But only if `x` is not used (i.e. not free)" should be "But only if `x` is not free (i.e. it is not used or is an argument)". I originally wrote it that way around but changed it the other way to make it simpler. Unfortunately that changed the meaning :)

Answer (score 9):

Well, [here's the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables), for what that's worth.

The short version is that such definitions elide the body of a lambda expression using a placeholder like "M", and so have to specify additionally that the variable being bound by that lambda isn't used in whatever the placeholder represents.

So, a "free variable" here roughly means a variable defined in some ambiguous or unknown outer scope--e.g., in an expression like `\y -> x + y`, `x` is a free variable but `y` is not.

Eta reduction is about removing a superfluous layer of binding and immediately applying a variable, which is (as you would probably imagine) only valid if the variable in question is only used in that one place.